# CSS Div Positioning

Tags: css, html

I am trying to build a two column header with minimum width of 1024px. I would like the window to cut of the right side of the site when a viewer's screen is smaller than 1024px, but I keep getting weird results, like the left side moving in. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Dynamic Drive: CSS Liquid Layout #2.1- (Fixed-Fluid)</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url(images/bground.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
min-width:1024px;
background-image:url(images/header_middle.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
}

#contentcolumn{
margin-left: 351px; /*Set left margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
background-image:url(images/header_right.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:318px;
    background-position:right;
}

#leftcolumn{
float: left;
width: 351px; /*Width of left column*/
margin-left: -100%;
background-image:url(images/header_left.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:300px;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="contentwrapper">
<div id="contentcolumn"></div>
</div>

<div id="leftcolumn">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

### CSS

```
div.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
div.one {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
}
div.two {
    height: 300px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">The left column</div>
    <div class="two">The right column</div>
</div>​
```

### Live Example

http://jsfiddle.net/HKrbn/

Comment: Thanks. I was really over thinking it.